# JQuery UI and Autocomplete Conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working on a Wordpress site which has both JQuery UI and Autocomplete loading. It looks like JQuery UI is loaded by a plugin (Ultimate VC Addons) which is required on the site. It is loading from:

```
wp-content/plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/assets/min-js/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3.16.6
```

Autocomplete is loaded by default (no plugin) from:

```
wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4
```

I'm trying to use the autocomplete feature, but have realized that the reason it isn't working is because of this conflict.

Here's my autocomplete code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(function () {
        var results = [
            "ActionScript",
            "Bootstrap",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Ecommerce",
            "Jquery",
            "Groovy",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lua",
            "Perl",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Swing",
            "XHTML"
        ];
        $("#autocomplete-cert").autocomplete(results);
    });

});
</script>
```

And:

```
<label for="autocomplete-cert">Search for a Certificate: </label>
<input id="autocomplete-cert">
```

Upon typing anything into the input box, the following error is thrown:

```
autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function
```

I've read that removing autocomplete in favor of JQuery UI is the right approach, but I can't find any code on the site that's referencing autocomplete.min.js, and therefore am having trouble removing it. I've tried removing the script outright, but the site throws errors that it is unable to find autocomplete.min.js after I remove it.

Does anyone know where Wordpress would be loading autocomplete from, or a way to disable it? I've searched the entire codebase and the only reference I've found to it is inside wp-admin/includes/update-core.php. Removing it from this file does not cause it to stop loading autocomplete.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question along with any errors you're getting

Comment: I've added the code I'm trying, as well as the error thrown, and the locations from which autocomplete and Jquery-ui are loading. The website is running on WP 4.5.3, with the Ultimate VC Addons plugin installed. This should be enough to recreate the environment which I'm receiving the error in. Please let me know if there's anything else I can clarify to help make this a more complete question. Thanks!